# Display posts on a map

Tags: mobile, google-maps, google

The wordpress mobile app lets you store gps position as option for each post. I would like to have a map that displays a point for each post.
I saw a lot of questions about this, most of them are quite old. I don't know since when the mobile app lets you add your position as option for the post, but I would like to use this native function instead of external plugin. 
Any help?

Comment: The app is just saving the values as meta for post. Prob LAT/LNG coordinates. You will need to write a plugin that utilizes a map API of some kind to plot them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GPS position is saved on two post meta fields: **geo_latitude** and **geo_longitude**.

You can use these meta values to draw the posts as markers on a Google Maps.

For example, using Google Maps API, you could have a template like this:

```php
<h1>Posts on map</h1>

<div id="map" style="height: 400px;"></div>
<script>

    // init map with the values you need
    function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 1,
        center: {lat: 0, lng: 0}
    });


    // get all posts that have meta_key geo_latitude
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( array( 'meta_key' => 'geo_latitude' ) ); ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php 
            // get latitude and longitude from post meta
            $geo_latitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'geo_latitude', true );
            $geo_longitude = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'geo_longitude', true ); 
        ?>
        <?php if(!empty( $geo_latitude ) && !empty( $geo_longitude )): ?>
            var pos = {lat: <?php echo $geo_latitude; ?>, lng: <?php echo $geo_longitude; ?>};
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              position: pos,
              map: map,
              title: '<?php the_title(); ?>'
            });
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
  }
</script>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
```